# Question on text layout templates

Tags: sharepoint-designer

im trying to design a SharePoint page for my departments site and have found the text layout options a bit limited for what i need.

ive tried editing in SP designer, but cant quite get it to work how i need it.

what im looking for is a layout as follows;

row 1 - two columns

row 2 - one column

row 3 - two columns

row 4 - one column

is anyone able to help me by providing the necessary code i can place into SP designer to create this layout?  any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks in advance,
mikey

Answer (score 0):

you should consider custom page layout.

you can make one in SharePoint designer. Check this link out:
Steps To Create Page Layouts In SharePoint 2013 Using SharePoint Designer
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-page-layouts-in-sharepoint-2013-using-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response although i havent been able to work out how to create a page layout using that.  it just shows me how to create a template that has a table already on it.